# I comment middleware Cors and VerifyCsrfToken, but when I try to send GET request from Laravel(Front end : react), still return Cors policy error

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I comment middleware Cors and VerifyCsrfToken, but when I try to send GET requefrom Laravel(Front end : react), still return Cors policy error.

request: 'http://localhost:3000'
receive:  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/getCSRFToken'

//////////////////////////////Back End///////////////////////////////////////////

getCSRFToken is a function written in Laravel HomeController.php file, the function has no problem to return a token when I used the app POSTMAN to get the request.Error only happens when I try to use react to send request.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function getCSRFToken(){
        return csrf_token();
    }
}
```

Here is my Kernel.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array<int, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class, 
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
       // \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,  commented
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,  commented
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
   
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array<string, array<int, class-string|string>>
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class, 
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's middleware aliases.
     *
     * Aliases may be used instead of class names to conveniently assign middleware to routes and groups.
     *
     * @var array<string, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $middlewareAliases = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
}
```

Here is my web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\StudentController;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;

Route::get('/getCSRFToken',[HomeController::class,'getCSRFToken']);
```

//////////////////////////////Front End///////////////////////////////////////////
Here is my Front end react page register.jsx

I use axios

```
  function onSubmit (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/getCSRFToken')
    .then(res=>{
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(error=>{
        console.log(error);
    })
```

Browser return

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/getCSRFToken' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I even tried uncomment VerifyCsrfToken.php and tried to put /getCSRFToken into protected $exceptarray like this , browser still return the same error. Please help

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $except = [
     
      
        '/getCSRFToken',
    ];
}
```

Comment: I don't know who voted you down. I think every single developer has this problem the first time they hear of CORS. Lol.  So, you can't just decide not to use CORS because it is a browser thing.  Your FE and BE are on different domains and CORS is designed to restrict that.  Just google "laravel CORS" and you'll get some good answers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

CORS issue occur due to different URL for front-end (http://127.0.0.1:8000/) and back-end (http://127.0.0.1:3000/). So, if you would like to resolve the CORS issue, follow below steps.

1. Create your route in `api.php`

   ```
   Route::get('test-route', [HomeController::class, 'test_method']);
   ```
2. Use this API `route with the api prefix`, as shown below.

   ```
   http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test-route
   ```
3. Now create custom middleware to resolve the CORS issue.

   ```
   php artisan make:middleware CustomCors
   ```
4. Put the below code in that custom middleware located in `App\Http\Middleware`.

   ```
   <?php
   namespace App\Http\Middleware;
   use Closure;
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;

   class CustomCors
   {
       public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
       {
           return $next($request)
           ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
           ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*')
           ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
           ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,Content-Type,X-Token-Auth,Authorization')
           ->header('Accept', 'application/json');
       }
   }
   ?>
   ```
5. Finally, register your custom middleware in kernel.php for all the routes, which is located at `App\Http\Kernel.php`.

   ```
   <?php 
   protected $middleware = [
       \App\Http\Middleware\CustomCors::class,
       // Others middlewares
   ];
   ?>
   ```

Comment: I hope provided solution will be helpful to you.

Comment: This looks like a chat GPT solution.  It solves 1 problem.  It's fine but it removes all CORS security with the wildcard '*'.

Comment: It's not a Chat GPT solution. You could verify it in Chat GTP portal.

Comment: Why I need to create a custom cors? why I cannot just use the original cors?

Comment: You can use that one also. I just shared my code which i was previously used in my project and which was working fine for me.

Comment: Once your code works fine then after change 
=>    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
with 
=>    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:3000')

Comment: Sorry, it is not working.

Comment: Could you please share screenshot of the error?

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/getcsrftoken' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.